# Convert strings from input file to tuple list

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a input file & it contains:

```
TEST.JOB
TEST.LAST_LOGIN,10
TEST.DATA,12
TEST.QUEUE_PARAM,09
TEST.ENTITY_PROFILE
```

I am expecting the return as below tuple list:

```
[('TEST','JOB'),('TEST','LAST_LOGIN','10'),('TEST','DATA','12'), .....]
```

Please advise how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just editing Yassine Faris' post, but it is deleted. It was actually right answer with lack of code.

```
with open("input_file.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    # It will going to split string from every dot and comma
    result = [tuple(l.strip().replace(',', '.').split(".")) for l in lines]
    # Result: [('TEST', 'JOB'), ('TEST', 'LAST_LOGIN', '10'), ('TEST', 'DATA', '12'), ('TEST', 'QUEUE_PARAM', '09'), ('TEST', 'ENTITY_PROFILE')]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way.

```
# extract date into list of lists prior to this logic
lst = ['TEST.JOB',
       'TEST.LAST_LOGIN,10',
       'TEST.DATA,12',
       'TEST.QUEUE_PARAM,09',
       'TEST.ENTITY_PROFILE']

# initialise list
res = []

# iterate and append
for item in lst:
    cat, detail = item.split('.')
    app = [cat] + detail.split(',')
    res.append(app)

# convert list of lists to list of tuples
res = list(map(tuple, res))
```

Result:

```
[('TEST', 'JOB'),
 ('TEST', 'LAST_LOGIN', '10'),
 ('TEST', 'DATA', '12'),
 ('TEST', 'QUEUE_PARAM', '09'),
 ('TEST', 'ENTITY_PROFILE')]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple one-liner:

```
lst = ['TEST.JOB',
       'TEST.LAST_LOGIN,10',
       'TEST.DATA,12',
       'TEST.QUEUE_PARAM,09',
       'TEST.ENTITY_PROFILE']
 result = [tuple(line.replace('.',' ').replace(',',' ').split()) for line in lst]
 print(result)
```

Result:

```
[('TEST', 'JOB'), ('TEST', 'LAST_LOGIN', '10'), ('TEST', 'DATA', '12'), ('TEST', 'QUEUE_PARAM', '09'), ('TEST', 'ENTITY_PROFILE')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use regular expressions to split with multiple deliminator.

import re
with open('input_file.txt') as f:
    data = [tuple(re.split("\.|\,", val.strip())) for val in f.readlines()]

#Output
[('TEST', 'JOB'), ('TEST', 'LAST_LOGIN', '10'), ('TEST', 'DATA', '12'), ('TEST', 'QUEUE_PARAM', '09'), ('TEST', 'ENTITY_PROFILE')]
```